# Retrieve data from another table if there is a matching value - else return based on first join condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to fetch data from two tables by joining them on a primary column. However, if the secondary and tertiary column are available in the right table then consider them and return its corresponding column.

```
LEFT_TAB
USER  PRIMARY  SECONDARY  TERTIARY
1       A1       B1        (null)
2       X1     (null)      (null)

RIGHT_TAB
PRIMARY SECONDARY TERTIARY INDICATOR
  A1       B1      (null)    I1
  A1     (null)    (null)    I2
  X1     (null)    (null)    I3

Expected Output:
USER  PRIMARY  SECONDARY  TERTIARY INDICATOR
  1     A1         B1      (null)    I1
  2     X1       (null)    (null)    I3
```

I have tried INNER JOIN on PRIMARY as that's the primary column and SECONDARY & TERTIARY are optional. If they're available then we use them and corresponding rows (LEFT OUTER JOIN) but it returns duplicate.

```
select lft.user_id,lft.primary,lft.secondary,lft.tertiary,rit.indication
from left_tab lft
INNER JOIN right_tab rit ON left.primary = rit.primary
LEFT JOIN right_tab rite ON
(left.secondary = rite.secondary OR left.tertiary = rite.tertiary) ---(join that's bringing dups)
;

OUTPUT:
USER  PRIMARY  SECONDARY  TERTIARY INDICATOR
  1     A1         B1      (null)    I1
  1     A1         B1      (null)    I2 --duplicate
  2     X1       (null)    (null)    I3
```

Comment: I'd avoid `left` as table alias, because `left inner join` looks very strange. (Also, seems like Oracle is more or less alone not having it as reserved, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.)

Comment: Also you can't (or at least shouldn't) use the same alias for different instances of the same table- you've used "rit" twice

Comment: Updated as per the above comments.

Comment: Of course it returns duplicates as long as you have two rows with `A1` in `RIGHT_TAB`. How Oracle should know *your expectations* or why *you* consider one row as preferrable over the other one? More interesting case is `A1 null C1 I3` and `A1 B2 C2 I4` additional rows in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT l.user_id,
       l.primary,
       l.secondary,
       l.tertiary,
       r.indicator
from   left_tab l
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT r.*
         FROM   right_tab r
         WHERE  l.primary = r.primary
         AND    (l.secondary = r.secondary OR r.secondary IS NULL)
         AND    (l.tertiary = r.tertiary OR r.tertiary IS NULL)
         ORDER BY (CASE WHEN r.secondary IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                  + CASE WHEN r.tertiary  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) r;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE LEFT_TAB (USER_ID, PRIMARY, SECONDARY, TERTIARY) AS
SELECT 1, 'A1', 'B1', CAST(null AS VARCHAR2(2)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'X1', null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE RIGHT_TAB (PRIMARY, SECONDARY, TERTIARY, INDICATOR) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'B1', CAST(null AS VARCHAR2(2)), 'I1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', null, null, 'I2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X1', null, null, 'I3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y1', null, 'Y3', 'I4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'I5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y1', 'Y2', null, 'I6' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | USER_ID | PRIMARY | SECONDARY | TERTIARY | INDICATOR |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A1 | B1 |  | I1 |
> | 2 | X1 |  |  | I3 |
> | 3 | Y1 | Y2 | Y3 | I5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f39b82461bb9e12cfc32e97354ac7683)*